# Mean Value Theory Application; function involve trig functions

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

> Given that $(n-x)\cos x = \sin x$ where $n>0,\;$ I need to prove that a root
>   exists in the interval $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ and that the equation
>   doesn't have roots if $n=0$ or $n < 0$ in the given interval.

First, $$(n-x)\cos x = \sin x \Rightarrow n = \frac{\sin x + x\cos x}{\cos x}$$
Since it is given that the interval is $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ therefore an $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$ which means that we're in the first quarter in the unit circle. Therefore $0 < \sin x < 1$ and $0<\cos x< 1$. As a result the expression $\frac{\sin x + x\cos x}{\cos x}$ can never be negative or equal zero.

Now to prove that a root exists in the interval $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ where $n > 0$ we can use the middle value theorem. Firstly, let $E(x) = (n-x)\cos x-\sin x$. $E(x)$ is continuous ($n$, $x$ are polynomes while $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are always continuous). Let $n = 0.5$. Thus:
$$
E(0.1) > 0 \qquad E(0.6) <0
$$
According to the middle value theorem there must be a root in the interval $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$. I'm not sure that I can just decide that $n$ is for example $0.5$ I guess I need to prove this for any $n > 0$.

Comment: Click "edit" to compare the formatting in the input field, with the output that renders.  Basically, the main fixes I made were with respect to cosine and sin. Your expression inputted for the numerator, in the equation of $n$ rendered as $sinx+xcosx$, compared to `$\sin x + x\cos x $`, and which renders $\sin x + x\cos x$

Comment: thanks, I wasn't aware that there was a way to make it prettier.

Comment: Learn the essentials first, then along the way, if you're, say looking to format something, and you see the output you'd like for your input, you can right-click over the function/equation/matrix, of interest, you'll see the first menu with "Show math as ->", highlight it, and to the right of the first menu will appear a list of options to highlight. Highlight and click on the option: "TeX commands"

Comment: Anyway, the back slash works with most functions (operators) you'll come across. Examples `\cos x, \sin x, \ldots, \ln x, \det A, \gcd(a, b), \int_a^b f(x)\,dx,` = $\cos x, \sin x, \ldots, \ln x, \det A, \gcd(a, b), \int_a^b f(x)\,dx$

Comment: great thanks for the tip

Comment: These comments are not aimed at criticizing you.  Your original post was completely legible and understandable.   I just know that I learned mathjax, Tex, etc. as I went along, paying as much attention to finding an example that's been formatted, to teach me how to do it, as the need arises.

Comment: I know no offence taken. And I do appreciate your example I wasn't aware that the slash can transform any function into something prettier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n>0$, then$E(0)=n>0$ and $E(\pi/2)=-1<0$. Hence there is $x_0 \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ such that $E(x_0)=0$

Comment: Thanks! What do you think about the part where I need to prove that $n$ cannot be negative or equal zero, is the proof correct? It's purely trigonometrical but I think I need to prove it somehow via middle value theorem too.

Comment: Yes, if $n \le0$ , then your proof is correct.